# Proof continuity of a function in a point by sequences

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In my analysis class I learned there are at least three equivalent ways to look at continuity. Consider $f:A \subseteq\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then we can say:

\begin{equation}
\bullet \textrm{$f$ is continuous in $a$ iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)<\epsilon|$ for all $x \in A$ with $|x-a|$} \\
\bullet \textrm{$f$ is continuous in $a$ iff for every sequence $(x_n)_n$ in A that converges to $a$ we have that $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(a)$} \\
\bullet \textrm{$f$ is continuous iff for every open $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is $f^{-1}(V)$ is relatively open}
\end{equation}

The first notions of continuity are local, whereas the third is global. Can anyone show how to use the second characterization of continuity (with sequences) to proof continuity of a function in a point? Every example I see proves continuity using the first or third characterization. Maybe answer can use the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto 2x$ as a sparring partner. So if possible, please only make use of  sequences in your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that $f$ is continuous at some point $a$, let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$; you wanto to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2x_n=2a$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\frac\varepsilon2>0$, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
n\ge N\implies|x_n-a|<\frac\varepsilon2.
$$
But then
$$
n\ge N\implies|2x_n-2a|=2|x_n-a|<\varepsilon.
$$